# Custom is Obsolete

Tags: fluentvalidation

I updated a project to the latest version of Fluent Validation and I get a warning:

```
'AbstractValidator<AccountSignInModel>.Custom(Func<AccountSignInModel, ValidationFailure>)' 
is obsolete: 'Use model-level RuleFor(x => x) instead'
```

When I am using the following code:

```
  When(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Password) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Username), () => {

    Custom(x => {

      Boolean valid = service.ValidateCredentials(x.Username, x.Password));

      if (!valid)
        return new ValidationFailure("Credentials", "Authentication failed");

      return null;

    });

  });
```

I don't know how to convert this into a `RuleFor(x => x)`.

Or is there another alternative to custom?

Answer (score 0):

We decided to use Fluent Validation recently on our application. So I am fairly new to this, figuring stuff as we go forward.

Stumbled upon your issue while searching for a different issue. There are not many resources on this. Thought I would share my thoughts, if it can help you. 
Here is what I would do.

```
public NewCustomValidator(Interface int)
    {
        CascadeMode = CascadeMode.Continue; // you could use StopOnFirstFailure or Continue

        RuleFor(x=> x.UserName).NotEmpty(); // Will return an error if null or empty
        RuleFor(x=> x.Password).NotEmpty();

        RuleSet("SomeNameHere", () =>
        {
            CascadeMode = CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure;
            var isValid = false;
            RuleFor(x=> new { x.UserName, x.Password })
            .Must((u , p) =>
            {
                valid = ValidateCredentials(u, p);
                return valid;
            })
            .WithMessage("You can show any message if you want");

            RuleFor(x => x.UserName).Must((s) => isValid);
            RuleFor(x => x.Password).Must((s) => isValid);
        });


    }
```

So, I am basically using your method to define in a Rule Set. You may have to add some code to validate the ruleSet.

```
 var result = validator.Validate(NewCustom, ruleSet: "SomeNameHere");
```

Disclaimer: This code may not compile. But it will give you an idea on how to approach the problem. If you have better ideas or If you could make the code work, please post the answer. That will help me gain some more knowledge. Thanks.